# Is there a better way to call UDF from a linked server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I was inherited a stored procedure from my former counterpart that uses a user-defined function from a linked server. The calling server uses sql server 2008 and the linked server uses sql server 2005 with 2000 compatibility.

Since calling UDFs from a linked server is not permitted, what he did was to duplicate the function on the calling server. The function takes one parameter and returns a scalar int value. It is used in one of the select columns in the stored procedure:

```
select 
columnA,
columnB,
fn_Function(columnC) as columnC_Alias
from TableD
```

This all works fine, but problem could arise if the function on the linked server gets updated by someone who's unaware of this duplication on the calling server creating inconsistencies between the two versions.

I am aware of the method of creating an SP on the linked server to encapsulate the function, but it doesn't quite work here.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Are you passing parameters to it?  Your example has none.  If so, please give us a more representative example.

Comment: Yes it does. Just the one and it returns a scalar int value, nothing too complicated.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that select statement in a view and calling the view from your SP in the calling server?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I think that was rather a suggestion than simply a question, even if it looked like one.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the value of the parameter that you are passing is dependent on the table you could wrap both the table and the UDF in a view and refer to the view from within your SP:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewD AS
SELECT columnA,
       columnB,
       columnC_Alias = fn_Function(columnC)
FROM   TableD
```